# Admin overlay missing in drupal7 with zen theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm creating a site in Drupal 7 with the Zen theme. When I started it had an admin overlay whenever I hovered over blocks that let me configure the block or the view that generated it(if applicable). Recently, the menu vanished and I'm unable to figure out how to get it back.

I looked at my modules, and noticed that some have been disabled (Views UI, Dashboard, and Overlay among others). I reenabled the modules but my overlay still has not returned. How can I go about debugging this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to enable one more module...Contextual links.